# AndEngine Error with PhysicsWorld

Tags: andengine

i am new with java and andengine and try to make the released jumper game to learn how it works. all fine now but if i try to load the PhysicsWorld i will get as follow errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
          Process: com.alex.neuertest, PID: 15463
          java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.alex.neuertest-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so"
          at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:972)
          at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
          at org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.<clinit>(PhysicsWorld.java:35)
          at com.alex.neuertest.GameScene.createPhysics(GameScene.java:345)
          at com.alex.neuertest.GameScene.createScene(GameScene.java:96)
          at com.alex.neuertest.BaseScene.<init>(BaseScene.java:41)
          at com.alex.neuertest.GameScene.<init>(GameScene.java:0)
          at com.alex.neuertest.Core.SceneManager$1.onTimePassed(SceneManager.java:148)
          at org.andengine.engine.handler.timer.TimerHandler.onUpdate(TimerHandler.java:94)
          at org.andengine.engine.handler.UpdateHandlerList.onUpdate(UpdateHandlerList.java:47)
          at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdateUpdateHandlers(Engine.java:618)
          at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:605)
          at org.andengine.engine.LimitedFPSEngine.onUpdate(LimitedFPSEngine.java:57)
          at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:568)
          at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:858)
```

maybe anyone can help me whats there wrong? how i said, iam new on this system xD

Comment: unrelated, but don't use AndEngine anymore, the engine is dead and is not under developement anymore

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the library for physics box was not found. You have to add physicsbox2dextenstion.so file in app folder as shown in picture. You may be clear after watching picture. Hope this help you.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Project not able to find `libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so`. Check do you have `.so` files inside your project. For different cpu architecture there are three `.so` file inside [AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension).

[image]